# Does something like a auto-function-list exist?

Tags: hooks

I had the following hook:

```el
(add-hook 'image-mode-hook 'imagex-sticky-maximize)
```

`imagex-sticky-maximize` is a function that maximizes the image to the borders of the window. I prefer to see my images to his fullest inside the window.

This works fine so far. But I noticed that Emacs crashes if the next file is a `*.gif` file. So disabling the `imagex-sticky-maximize` helps.
But I would like to enable that function when the file is a `*.PNG`, or `*.JPG` or `*.TIFF` image.

So I was looking for a solution. I know you have the `auto-mode-alist`. When you declare something like this:

```el
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.clj$\\'" . paredit-mode))
```

Then paredit mode will be called as minor mode, when you open file with the extension `*.clj`. This works only for minor modes.
I was looking for a sort of `auto-function-alist`, that calls `imagex-sticky-maximize` when a specifix extension is being opened. However, I couldn't find anything of this.

Any suggestion in that direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily write your own function that checks the extension of the file name of the current buffer, and call a function if it does (or doesn't) match.

For example (warning: untested):

```el
(defun my-image-mode-hook ()
  (let ((name (buffer-file-name)))
    (when name
      (let ((ext (file-name-extension name)))
        (unless (string= (downcase ext) "gif")
          (imagex-sticky-maximize))))))
(add-hook 'image-mode-hook 'my-image-mode-hook)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It would be a good idea indeed. Your function doesn't nothing by the way, you need to `(add-hook 'image-mode-hook 'my-image-mode-hook)`.

Comment: @ReneFroger, thanks, answer updated! (Damn you auto completion...)